# SQL Server Full Text Search: different results of parsing forms of words

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Why these queries have the different results in sqlserver 2008R2 and sqlserver (2012, 2014, 2016, 2017)?

```
--SQLSERVER 2008R2
SELECT display_term FROM SYS.DM_FTS_PARSER('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, test)', 1033, 0, 0)
----------
tests
tested
testing
test

SELECT display_term FROM SYS.DM_FTS_PARSER('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, testing)', 1033, 0, 0)
---------
tests
tested
testing
test
```

The 2nd query:

```
--SQLSERVER 2016
SELECT display_term FROM SYS.DM_FTS_PARSER('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, test)', 1033, 0, 0)
----------
test's
tested
testing
tests
tests'
test

SELECT display_term FROM SYS.DM_FTS_PARSER('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, testing)', 1033, 0, 0)
---------
test
test's
tested
testing's
testings
testings'
tests
tests'
testing
```

I have supposed it should be the same but in my production db a clients have some problems with this kind of different behavior.

These are wordbreakers:

```
--2008r2
wordbreaker 1033    188D6CC5-CB03-4C01-912E-47D21295D77E    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\Binn\langwrbk.dll  12.0.6828.0 Microsoft Corporation
-- 2012
wordbreaker 1033    9FAED859-0B30-4434-AE65-412E14A16FB8    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL2012\MSSQL\Binn\MsWb7.dll  14.0.4763.1000  Microsoft Corporation
-- 2014
wordbreaker 1033    9FAED859-0B30-4434-AE65-412E14A16FB8    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER2014\MSSQL\Binn\MsWb7.dll  14.0.4763.1000  Microsoft Corporation
-- 2016
wordbreaker 1033    9FAED859-0B30-4434-AE65-412E14A16FB8    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\MSSQL\Binn\MsWb7.dll  14.0.4763.1000  Microsoft Corporation
-- 2017
wordbreaker 1033    9FAED859-0B30-4434-AE65-412E14A16FB8    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\MSSQL\Binn\MsWb7.dll  14.0.4763.1000  Microsoft Corporation
```

Comment: This looks like a tough one.  Could it be related to a database setting for word breakers?  Perhaps 2008 has ' as a word breaker?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-word-breakers-and-stemmers-for-search?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I have checked on other versions too: the difference between 2008R2 and (2012, 2014, 2016, 2017).

Comment: Please see the 1st post I have added the info about wordbreakers.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft changed the worbreakers set in 2012. The new breakers have other behavior in comparison with 2008. That is the reason.